# How to catch specific Postgres exceptions in Python psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql

Default psycopg2 error messages are too broad. Most of the time it simply throws:

> psycopg2.OperationalError

without any additional information. So it is hard to guess, what was the real reason of the error - either incorrect user credentials, or simply the fact the server is not running. So, I need some more appropriate error handling, like error codes in `pymysql` library.

I've seen [this](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/errorcodes.html) page, but it does not help. When I do

```
except Exception as err:
    print(err.pgcode)
```

it always prints None. And as for `errorcodes` it is simply undefined. I tried to import it, but failed. So, I need some help.

Comment: Can you share a full snippet please?

Comment: Any code will work. for example, `try: cnx = psycopg2.connect(...) except Exception as err: ...`

Comment: It's not *any* code that seems to produce limited error messages (without error codes set). It's code *before* the connection has been established. Once you have a connection up, you get proper error messages. Please be specific.

Comment: Guys, what I'm interested in, is how to get error codes, like it is defined in documentation, but does not work - http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/errorcodes.html . Now I always get `psycopg2.OperationalError` and some or no error messages. Yes, these error messages may differ, but should I parse long scrolls of messages to understand what is going on?

Comment: @Jacobian There is no error code from `connect()`. If you look at `psycopg2.errorcodes`, there is no status for e.g. "Authentication failed". You only get the error codes (in `.pgcode`) once you have a functioning connection object. Before you have that, the underlying library only offers [PQerrorMessage()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-status.html#LIBPQ-PQERRORMESSAGE) which gives you the error string you see in the exception. There's no way to access more information, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, dhke! Now I got it. Will check it in a second.

Comment: @dhke Thanks for the info! I'm not sure which version you were looking at because this question was almost 5 years ago. Now (v`2.8.7`) the [`errorcodes`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/errors.html) has `28000` and `28P01`. The page says they are about "invalid authorization". I know that, technically, "authentication" and "authorization" are two different things, but I was surprised that `psycopg2` doesn't have any error code about authentication, so this makes me wonder if they handle authentication and authorization as one thing.

Comment: @dhke Do you mind sharing how you learned "You only get the error codes (in .pgcode) once you have a functioning connection object. Before you have that, the underlying library only offers PQerrorMessage() which gives you the error string you see in the exception"? Did you read it somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: @yaobin psycopg2 wraps [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq.html), PostgreSQL's C library. Libpq will almost always give you a connection object that you can query for errors. However, if the connection itself is "bad",  there does not seem to be a documented way to obtain a detailed error code, you just get the error message.

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone looking a quick answer:**

### Short Answer

```
import traceback  # Just to show the full traceback
from psycopg2 import errors

InFailedSqlTransaction = errors.lookup('25P02')

            try:
                feed = self._create_feed(data)
            except InFailedSqlTransaction:
                traceback.print_exc()
                self._cr.rollback()
                pass # Continue / throw ...
```

### Long Answer

1. Go to `psycopg2 -> erros.py`   you will find the lookup function `lookup(code)`.
2. Go to `psycopg2\_psycopg\__init__.py` in `sqlstate_errors` you will find all codes to add as string into the `lookup` function.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question but merely my thoughts that don't fit in a comment. **This is a scenario in which I think setting `pgcode` in the exception object would be helpful but, unfortunately, it is not the case.**

I'm implementing a `pg_isready`-like Python script to test if a Postgres service is running on the given address and port (e.g., `localhost` and `49136`). The address and port may or may not be used by any other program.

`pg_isready` internally calls [`internal_ping()`](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/fe-connect_8c.html#a81cdb2f1cd25adf0db94b9088bf88122). Pay attention to the comment of `Here begins the interesting part of "ping": determine the cause...`:

```c
     /*
      * Here begins the interesting part of "ping": determine the cause of the
      * failure in sufficient detail to decide what to return.  We do not want
      * to report that the server is not up just because we didn't have a valid
      * password, for example.  In fact, any sort of authentication request
      * implies the server is up.  (We need this check since the libpq side of
      * things might have pulled the plug on the connection before getting an
      * error as such from the postmaster.)
      */
     if (conn->auth_req_received)
         return PQPING_OK;
```

So `pg_isready` also uses the fact that an error of invalid authentication on connection means the connection itself is already successful, so the service is up, too. Therefore, I can implement it as follows:

```py
        ready = True

        try:
            psycopg2.connect(
                host=address,
                port=port,
                password=password,
                connect_timeout=timeout,
            )
        except psycopg2.OperationalError as ex:
            ready = ("fe_sendauth: no password supplied" in except_msg)
```

However, when the exception `psycopg2.OperationalError` is caught, `ex.pgcode` is `None`. Therefore, I can't use the error codes to compare and see if the exception is about authentication/authorization. I'll have to check if the exception has a certain message (as @dhke pointed out [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851375/how-to-catch-specific-postgres-exceptions-in-python-psycopg2#comment63164178_37851375)), which I think is kind of fragile because the error message may be changed in the future release but the error codes are much less likely to be changed, I think.